# Why is the conductivity of NaCl, NaBr and NaI decreasing with temperature?

Tags: conductivity

I collected the conductivity of NaCl, NaBr, and NaI from 30 celsius to 80 celsius. I used the solutions mixed in water.
In all instances, the conductivity seemed to reduce as the temperature increased. I am unsure if it was an experimental error, or if my results actually make sense. Please state your reasons for thinking its an error or not.

Experiment Details: 50 ml, 0.1 molar of all solutions. I used vernier sensors for detecting the temperature and the conductivity.

For this experiment, I had a 50ml beaker on a hotplate and had the conductivity and temperature vernier sensors dipped in the liquid.
(I made sure the sensors are only touching the solution and not the bottom of the beaker). Then, I just waited for the hotplate to heat up the liquid to 80 Celsius.

From research, the opposite seems to be accurate, but I have conducted many trials giving the same trend of decreasing conductivity.
Source: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02877571

(This is my first question, please let me know any other details that would be required to answer this question )

Comment: I assume you are talking about solutions if the salts, not the salts themselves, right? And you have to provide a lot more details about your experiment as well as the results of your literature search to make this question answerable.

Comment: The trend [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287147827_Temperature_Effects_on_Conductivity_of_Seawater_and_Physiologic_Saline_Mechanism_and_Significance) (figure 1c, 0 to 30 centigrade) is a different one.  Yet your question doesn't state the salts' concentration, the equipment used, the design of the experiment (well yes, some replication is worth to *estimate* the significance of the results vs [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty), and [accuracy vs precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) of the readings.